# Crystal Report Tutorial

Tags: c#, forms, crystal-reports-2008

I am learning to use Crystal Report form in my C# Application. I can't seem to find any good tutorial on the net about it. The ones on MSDN pages looks disorganized to me.

Can anyone provide links to good Tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are totally new to Crystal Reports I would advise you to play a bit with the sample database that is attached to Crystal Reports `Xtreme.mdb` before you will use Crystal in Visual Studio.

To use CR in your application follow this step by step tutorial:

http://infynet.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/crystal-report-in-c/

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. It's a basic starter but I must add the language of the article is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this answer here, even though I haven't finished reading the document myself.  Also, this is for Visual Studio 2005 and I'm not sure if that is the one for which you are looking.  According to the copyright on the PDF, this was created by Business Objects.  Once I am done reading it entirely, I'll update my own opinion.

http://www.willydev.net/descargas/willydev_deployment_crystal2005.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hope it's an improvement over the earlier link posted.